# Angular js and bootstrap modal select box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, select, angular-ngmodel

Hey i'm trying updating a modal select box using angular and bootstrap modals

When i click the button i can't get it to update the related select box value in bootstrap modal.

i tryed like this but it doesn't works.

http://plnkr.co/edit/EaQhEGMTLx4omK5nxWHD?p=preview

Basically: if you click "Artist" button it should open modal and select the right select option

Any clue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving `<div id="app" ng-view></div>` to inside your main div to create correct parent-child relationship so that your modal's scope could inherit from your `AuthCtrl`' scope:

```
<div ng-controller="AuthCtrl">
    <div ng-include="'modal.html'"></div>
    <div id="app" ng-view>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/7g7uDr3PqiwPSvowv7jC?p=preview)

Comment: it works perfectly man thanks, BUT anyway to make it cleaner? without including ng-view in the AuthController ?

Comment: @sbaaaang: You're using `routeProvider`, so using `ng-view` is a must